# Writting a simple mail client and server, user authentication by using signature, verifying signature , user failed to login

Tags: java, sockets, cryptography, digital-signature, digest-authentication

**Here are my codes in github**. Click [here] https://github.com/bearer1024/cryptographyEmail

user failed to pass verifyLogin every times, even given with right .pub and .prv key. **I'm quite sure problem is about signature. But I don't know how to solve it.**

her are my running output in client side:
java MailClient localhost 1111 bearer

in the client,the length of signature is :256

false

failed to login

Here are running output in server side:

java MailServer 1111

Welcome...

in the server,the length of signature is:256

verifying for clientid is:bearer

Server position2

Client failed to log in

Client bearer failed to log in.

**client login codes:**

```
// connect to server
        Socket s = new Socket(host,port);
        DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(s.getInputStream());
        DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
        oos.flush();
        ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(s.getInputStream());

        // TO DO: login

        // these two lines are here just to make the supplied programs run without crashing.
        // You may want to change them, and certainly add things after them
        dos.writeUTF(userid);

        String userPrivateKeyFileName = userid + ".prv";
        // Get the key to create the signature
        ObjectInputStream keyIn = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(userPrivateKeyFileName));
        PrivateKey privateKey = (PrivateKey)keyIn.readObject();
        keyIn.close();

        // create timeStamp and random number
        long t1 = (new Date()).getTime();
        // ByteBuffer to convert to bytes later
        ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocate(16);
        bb.putLong(t1);
        bb.put(userid.getBytes());


        // create signature, using timeStamp and random number as data
        Signature sig = Signature.getInstance("SHA1withRSA");
        sig.initSign(privateKey);
        sig.update(bb.array());
        byte[] signature = sig.sign();

        // send data and signature
        dos.writeLong(t1);
        dos.writeInt(signature.length);
        System.out.println("in the client,the length of signature is :"+signature.length);
        dos.write(signature);
        dos.flush();

        boolean answer = dis.readBoolean();

        System.out.println(answer);
```

**server verifySignature code:**

```
 public static boolean verifyLogin(DataInputStream dis, String userid) throws Exception {

    // TO DO

    // receive data and signature

    long t1 = dis.readLong();
    //double q1 = dis.readDouble();
    int length = dis.readInt();
    System.out.println("in the server,the length of signature is:"+length);
    byte[] signature = new byte[length];
    System.out.println("verifying for clientid is:"+userid);
    dis.readFully(signature);
    System.out.println("Server position2");

    // ByteBuffer to convert to bytes later
    ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocate(16);
    bb.put(userid.getBytes());
    bb.putLong(t1);



    // should actually retrieve the appropriate key file using the received user name. For simplicity, hardcoded here
    String userPublicKeyFileName = userid + ".pub";
    ObjectInputStream keyIn = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(userPublicKeyFileName));
    PublicKey publicKey = (PublicKey)keyIn.readObject();
    keyIn.close();

    // verify signature
    Signature sig = Signature.getInstance("SHA1withRSA");
    sig.initVerify(publicKey);
    sig.update(bb.array());

    // verify timeSpan
    // server local timeStamp
    long t2 = (new Date()).getTime();
    long timeSpan = t2 - t1;
    boolean timeFresh = false;
    if (timeSpan < 60000)
        timeFresh = true;

    //final check
    /*if (sig.verify(signature)&&timeFresh){
        System.out.println("Client logged in");
        return true;}
    else{
        System.out.println("Client failed to log in");
        return false;}*/
    if (sig.verify(signature)){
        System.out.println("signature is right");
        if(timeFresh){
           System.out.println("timespan is fresh"); 
        }
        return true;}
    else{
        System.out.println("Client failed to log in");
        return false;}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

yeah, It's a stupid bug,cause I used datainputstream and dataoutputstream, cause **client output sequence and server input sequence should be same.**

```
// ByteBuffer to convert to bytes later
ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocate(16);
bb.put(userid.getBytes());
bb.putLong(t1);
```

This bug not so easy to find because I use bb.array(). lol.